# pandoc error converting inline mathjax in markdown document

Tags: markdown, pandoc, mathjax

I have a markdown document with mathjax. I want to convert it into pdf. I encounter an error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.67 \] Set (R\_2 \to

pandoc: Error producing PDF
```

I believe it is generated by inline mathjax `$R_2 \to R_2 + 2R_1$`. If I wrap it with `$$ ... mathjax ... $$` it gives proper result. How do I enable inline math with pandoc.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example? Random guess would be the underscores being turned into emphasis first which is not math mode.

Comment: should be enabled by default, see http://pandoc.org/README.html#math Also: `echo '$R_2 \to R_2 + 2R_1$' | pandoc -t latex` is properly escaped for me...

Comment: @mb21 I noticed that I had space in my wrappings `$ R_2 \to R_2 + 2R_1 $`. It seems that pandoc produced error because of it.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I found the error was due to space in my wrappings adjacent to `$`. It was being interpreted as `\$ R\_2 \to R\_2 + 2R\_1 \$`

Comment: So, since the question got its answer, please add an actual answer and accept it, so that it is not show among "unanswered" questions (also, those who are experiencing a similar problem will see that there's a solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem was the space between `$` and the latex code. For example, `$ R\_2 \to R\_2 + 2R\_1 $` was interpreted as `\$ R\_2 \to R\_2 + 2R\_1 \$` so removing space between solved the problem i.e. `$R\_2 \to R\_2 + 2R\_1$` worked out.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I got the same error when trying to convert a Jupyter Notebook to PDF with xeLatex and nbconvert.
I had a space in the name of my notebook. It worked when I removed it.